# Existing element after removing in jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh

I've an issue with refreshing in my code, I've tried to find different solutions that I found, but without any success.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).on("click",'.supact',function () {
        $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        var num = 1;
        $(".sact").each(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            $(this).attr("id", "pact" + num);
            num++;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

When the parent of the element is deleted (it's a div), if I had 2 div before, It would alert me only 1 div id, but it alerts me twice instead of once.

What do you think about it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found what was wrong, I hope it will help some of you !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click",'.supact',function () {
            $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function () {
                $(this).remove();
                var num = 1;
                $(".sact").each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("id", "pact" + num);
                    $(this).children('select').each(function () {
                        $(this).attr("id", "formact_id_value_liste" + num);
                        $(this).attr("name", "act_id_value_liste" + num);
                    });
                    $(this).children('label').each(function () {
                        $(this).attr("for", "formact_id_value_liste" + num);
                    });
                    num++;
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Also I added code to change label :)